# How are Blackberry world downloads counted?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

How are the downloads of app counted in blackberry world? Is it the number of times users pressed on downloads, or number of times the download was completed?

Answer (score 0):

Once an application is successfully installed, it is considered downloaded.

This way, BlackBerry World knows to display the proper view when you re-visit the app's product page (e.g. can show an 'upgrade' or 'open' icon)